# Python Selenium webdriver get XPATH and select dropdown

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've found the word 'Burger' in HTML table with this code

```
findRow = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'Burger')]").value_of_css_property('#name')
```

1. how do I can get XPATH 'Burger'?
2. how do I can select the column beside it (example select 'Fish' beside column 'Burger') and then submit button?

HTML code

```
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>..</td>
            <td>.....</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Burger</td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control input-sm" id="sel222" name="sel222" type="68" group="433" onchange="count(this)">
                    <option value="1">Vegetables</option>
                    <option value="2">Fish</option>
                    <option value="3">Beef</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>       
    </tbody>
</table>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit"><span class="fa fa-save"></span> Save</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the HTML posted, the simplest XPath to find "Burger" would be,

```
//td[text()='Burger']
```

The XPath to find the SELECT in the cell to the right of the "Burger" cell would be,

```
//td[text()='Burger']/following-sibling::td/select
  ^ the XPath to find the TD that contains "Burger", from above
                      ^ then find the sibling TD
                                            ^ then the SELECT child of the sibling
```

Putting this all together to select "Fish" from the SELECT element next to the "Burger" cell and click Submit,

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

select = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[text()='Burger']/following-sibling::td/select"))
select.select_by_visible_text("Fish")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "submit").click()
```

Comment: how to make sure column ::td/select is exist? because some row is merging/span column and show error message => TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

Comment: If it doesn't exist, the first line will throw a `NoSuchElementException`. There's nothing in my code that is concatenating strings so I'm not sure what you are referring to. You probably need to do some investigating and if you can't figure it out, create a new question with the code sample, error message, etc. and we'll help you.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, you can identify the select list box using xpath following technique. Use the below xpath to identify *select* object

```
//td[contains(.,'Burger')]/following::select
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the option `Burger` using the below XPath:

```
.//td[text()='Burger']
```

You can select the options inside `select` tag using the below XPath:

```
.//td[text()='Burger']//parent::tr//select/option
```